# How to compare two directories and move files unique (in name or contents) to the 1st directory elsewhere?

Tags: sorting, directory

I have two directories containing folders and files, as seen below

```
├───dir1
│   │   alpha
│   │   beta.txt
│   │   gamma.exe
│   │   zeta.BIN
│   │
│   ├───delta
│   │       iota.arc
│   │       theta.mp3
│   │
│   └───epsilon
│       │   upsilon.wfbs
│       │
│       └───phi
│               pi.dll
│               sigma.tar
│
└───dir2
    │   alpha
    │   beta.txt
    │   gamma.exe
    │
    ├───delta
    │       eta.zip
    │       iota.arc
    │       theta.mp3
    │
    └───epsilon
        │   upsilon.wfbs
        │
        └───phi
                kappa.dll
                sigma.tar
```

Some files have the same filenames, but different contents. For example, if  `alpha` and `iota.arc`  have different contents in `dir1` than `dir2`, then `dir3` (where the files different from `dir1` to `dir2` are moved) should look like this.

```
├───dir3
|   |   alpha
│   │   zeta.BIN
│   │
│   ├───delta
│   │       iota.arc
│   │
│   └───epsilon
│       │
│       └───phi
│               pi.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jdupes](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes) to do this, like so:

Windows:

```
jdupes.exe -O -R -d -N dir2 dir1
robocopy dir1 dir1 /S /MOVE
rename dir1 dir3
rmdir /S /Q dir2
```

Linux:

```
#! /bin/sh
./jdupes -O -R -d -N ./dir2 ./dir1
find ./dir1 -type d -empty -delete
mv ./dir1 ./dir3
rm -rf ./dir2
```

Note: These scripts/commands only work when they are executed in the same directory (which must also contain the jdupes binary) as the target directories.